# Is this question really off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, closed-questions, close-reasons

I just saw [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/78563/36369) question and wanted to add an answer. While I was composing my answer the question was closed as off-topic.

I'm a bit puzzled: although the question could have a slightly broad answer scope, it is fairly focused and it is about a real, concrete problem.

Maybe I misunderstood the help center directions about on-topic questions for this site, but I don't think is so blatantly off-topic and it has also produced a bunch of quality, focused, answers.

In particular, that question seems to be specifically covered by this point from the "on-topic" list (emphasis mine):

> **Maintaining employment** (promotions, pay increases, harassment, bullying, poor working conditions, **communication problems**, etc.)

Did I miss something, or was the question closed too hastily?

Comment: there were significant edits made after closing - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/78563/revisions

Comment: @RichardU I just cast the last reopen vote.

Comment: @enderland In my opinion, the revisions added clarity but not make the question significantly more or less on topic. Was the question off topic before the revisions?

Comment: @ThrowAway - In the eyes of the community yes.  I would not have voted to close nor would I have voted to reopen with out changes.  The crux of the issue was that the original question was not really workplace specific.